# nutch 1.15 index multiple cores with solr 7.5

Tags: indexing, solr, nutch

I'm using nutch 1.15 and solr 7.5 with **the need to index multiple cores**. I have created separate crawldb and linkdb for each core, and then updated index-writers.xml with multiple writers (each writer_id matching corresponding core's name). Also, param name="url" points to each solr core, but since there's no place to pass a param indicating the writer id nor the solr core, bin/nutch index command indexes an specific crawldb against all cores. Of course, I need to only index crawldb1 to core1.

Any suggestion on resolving this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [JEXL exchange](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Exchanges) to route documents from within the same crawl to different index writers. This would allow you route your documents into different Solr cores (one index writer per core with a different writer id.

This would allow you to run 1 instance of Nutch crawling all your domains of interest. I am assuming that you can also route your documents based on some property that its present in the crawled documents (URL, title, etc.).

Comment: Hi Jorge, thanks for the input. I tried this approach with two exchanges (use case 2 at https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Exchanges) each with a <writer> matching writer_id in index-writers.xml, but bin/crawl keeps saying "No exchange was configured. The documents will be routed to all index writers." Would this configuration work assuming we have various nutch instances? http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/nutch-1-15-index-multiple-cores-with-solr-7-5-td4419174.html